# Using the Remote Desktops MMC snap-in how do you connect to nonstandard ports?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

I have some severs I manage VIA Remote Desktop. They do not listen on port 3389. I can connect with out issue doing IP:PORT.

I now manage so many I'm trying to use the Remote Desktop snap-in for the management console. But it will not let you enter a colon in the host name.

Is there another way to specify the port?

Here is link to the [snap-in.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en)

EDIT:

I'm using XP... yeah I know I'm behind.

Comment: I tried both Royal TS and Terminals. I like Terminals better. But joeqwerty's answer is the most, correct you can't do it with the snap-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with the snap-in, but as others have suggested you can use a third party program to do it. I use [RoyalTS](http://code4ward.net/main/) myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is an option for you but it allows ports in the windows 7 adminpak
[Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether you wan to stick to the standard mmc, you might find useful Terminals, which will allow you to connect to many servers and save the configuration.

http://terminals.codeplex.com/